# Why am I getting error? TypeError: "Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

In main.js (not everything in there but what is having the problem):

```
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    }  else if (command == 'hello'){
        client.commands.get('hello').execute(message, args);
    }  else if (command == 'command'){
        client.commands.get('command').execute(message, args, Discord);
    }  else if (command == 'clear'){
        client.commands.get('clear').execute(message, args);
    }  else if (command == 'kick'){
        client.commands.get('kick').execute(message, args);
    }  else if (command == 'ban'){
        client.commands.get('ban').execute(message, args);
    }  else if (command == 'mute'){
        client.commands.get('mute').execute(message,args);
    }  else if (command == 'wake'){
        client.commands.get('wake up').execute(message,args);
    }  else if (command == 'play'){
        client.commands.get('play').execute(message, args);
    }  else if (command == 'leave'){
        client.commands.get('leave').execute(message, args);
    }  else if (command == 'coin'){
        client.commands.get('coin').execute(message, args, Discord);
    }  else if (command == 'avatar'){
        client.commands.get('avatar').execute(client, message, args);
    }  else if (command == 'weather'){
        client.commands.get('weather').execute(client, message, args);
    }  else if (command == 'slowmode'){
        client.commands.get('slowmode').execute(message, args);
    }  else if (command == 'youtube'){
        client.commands.get('youtube').execute(message, args);
    }  else if (command == 'kill'){
        client.commands.get('kill').execute(message, args);
    }  else if (command == 'beep'){
        client.commands.get('beep').execute(message, args, Discord);
    }  else if (command == 'spam'){
        client.commands.get('spam').execute(message, args, Discord);
    }  else if (command == 'reactionrole'){
        client.commands.get('reactionrole').execute(message, args, Discord);
    } 
});
```

Whats in reactionrole.js:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'reactionrole',
    description: "Sets up a reaction role message!",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
        const channel = '│announcements';
        const yellowTeamRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "New Role");
 
        const pepepog = 'pepepog';
 
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#e42643')
            .setTitle('Want A Custom Role?')
            .setDescription('Want Your own Custom Role? Yea, Thought So React In The Next 30 Minutes To Get Your Own Custom Role! @dioZ Will Make It When He Is Not Busy!!'
                + `${pepepog} for custom role :))`);
 
        let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
        messageEmbed.react(pepepog);
 
        client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === pepepog) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(yellowTeamRole);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
 
        });
 
        client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
 
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === pepepog) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(yellowTeamRole);               }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    }
 
}
```

Comment: `client.commands.get('reactionrole')` Is returning undefined. Also for future questions please format your code completely and only include the line(s) that are relevant to what you're asking about.

Comment: You might want to show us the error you get and format your code please ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is super simple to solve, you are mixing up events and commands with each other please move

```js
 client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === pepepog) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(yellowTeamRole);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
 
        });
 
        client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
 
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === pepepog) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(yellowTeamRole);               }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    }

 // To your mainfile as it is an event and furthermore check if reactionrole.js is being exported properly~! Hope it helps
```